# Union and left join of three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, union

I have three tables A, B, AB.

[image: Three tables]

Table A has 60 mobile numbers and a scoreA for each mobile number.
Table B has 40 mobile numbers and a scoreB for each mobile number.
Table AB has 40 mobile numbers from A and 10 mobile numbers from B and a scoreAB.

If a mobile exists only in Table A, it will only have scoreA.

If a mobile exists only in Table B, it will only have scoreB.

**If a mobile exists in both A and B, it will have scoreA, scoreB and scoreAB.**

I would like to create a new table with the following schema:

```
mobile    scoreA    scoreB    scoreAB
```

wherein, **from the 60 mobile numbers from Table A, 20 that don't exist in Table AB should have null values for scoreB, scoreAB.** The **remaining 40 that exist in Table AB should have all three scores.**

From the 40 mobile numbers from Table B, 30 that don't exist in Table AB should have null values for scoreA, scoreAB. The remaining 10 that exist in Table AB should have all three scores.

As of now, I did the following:

```
spark.sql(""" SELECT A.mobile as mobile_A
          FROM A 
          UNION
          SELECT B.mobile as mobile_B 
          FROM B
          UNION
          SELECT AB.mobile as mobile_AB
          FROM AB 
        """).createOrReplaceTempView('union_table')
```

Then,

```
spark.sql(""" SELECT u.mobile_A, 
                 A.score as scoreA, B.score as scoreB, AB.score as scoreAB
              FROM union_table as u
              LEFT JOIN A
              ON A.mobile = u.mobile_n 
              LEFT JOIN B
              ON B.mobile = u.mobile_n
              LEFT JOIN C
              ON C.mobile = u.mobile_n
      """).createOrReplaceTempView('scores_combined_table')
```

I am not getting the correct results. What is wrong with the above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `union all` and aggregation:

```
select mobile,
       max(scorea) as scorea,
       max(scoreb) as scoreb,
       max(scoreab) as scoreab
from ((select mobile, scorea, null as scoreb, null as scoreab
       from a
      ) union all
      (select mobile, null as scorea, scoreb, null as scoreab
       from b
      ) union all
      (select mobile, null as scorea, null as scoreb, scoreab
       from ab
      )
     ) ab
group by mobile;
```

This is implementing one version of a `full join` -- which MySQL does not support.  An alternative method uses `left join`:

```
select *
from (select mobile from a
      union -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select mobile from b
      union 
      select mobile from ab -- just in case there are other mobiles here
     ) m left join
     a
     using (mobile) left join
     b
     using (mobile)
     left join
     c
     using (mobile);
```

Comment: Wouldn't union all give me duplicate mobile numbers? I only want my final 100 mobile numbers, 40+10=50 of which will have all three scores

Comment: @Srivatsan . . . Not with `group by`.

Comment: Why is `max(scorea)` etc. needed? Why not just `scorea`?

Comment: @Srivatsan . . . Because of the aggregation.